# Price Rules Magento 2 show discount only if price difference is 5%

Tags: magento2, price-rules

I have a magento 2 store but all the prices are populated from a content management system. In this system, I have two prices retail ( manufacturer) that cannot be changed and my price. I want the show savings on the website only if the price difference is 5% between both prices. Please see image for an example
[image]

But I do not want the Savings to show up if the retail price is £280 and my price is £279. When I change the price in the special price it is always showing the discount.